# Can the Tier 2 General Visa sponsor employer force me to stay and work with them during the contract period?

Tags: united-kingdom, working-visas, uk-visa

Can my Tier 2 General Visa sponsor employer force me to stay and work with them during the contract period?

Is there any penalty for me if I switch my employer under the same category before the contract ends?

Can I switch employers whenever I want?

What's the cooling off period? Does that affect me if I want to switch employers during the first 12-month of my tier 2 general visa?